# v6 java upgrade is missing ChangeNotificationCollection classes

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I upgraded microsoft-graph-java from 5.80.0 to 6.4.0. I have been able to refactor all of the code so we can continue to query user data. However, This application also is a consumer of the subscription web hooks and in v6 the needed ChangeNotificationCollection class has been removed. After searching I found out that most of the objects that were removed in v6 can be created with the openapi.yaml file and the kiota tool. Unfortunately, the ChangeNotificationCollectionResponse is in the openapi.yaml but it is not used in any of the paths so it is not getting generated. What is the recommended solution to generate these missing classes so I can continue to process the calls we are receiving from the subscription web hook?

Here is the openapi.yaml file I am using. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-metadata/master/openapi/v1.0/openapi.yaml

Comment: I would recommend to create an issue in SDK repository https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues. I expect that they will fix it ASAP. It's sad that they released v6 with so many issues :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and created it [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues/1891), since there was no issue created yet.

Edit: They answered pretty fast and stated this as a bug in their generation tool.